# MS Project Server REST api from SharePoint-Hosted app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app, project-server

I'm trying to get some project data using the REST API. My queries work fine when using Postman. But when it comes to SharePoint-Hosted app, I'm getting a "404 (Not Found)" error.
My app is deployed on the PWA root web.
Here is my code:

```
function GetProject() {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();

        var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);

        var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

        var restQueryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/ProjectServer/Projects?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: encodeURI(restQueryUrl),
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body).d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                deferred.reject(JSON.parse(xhr.body).error.message.value);
            }
        });
        return deferred;
};
```

Would you have some inputs to solve my problem?
Thanks.

Regard,

Comment: I can't get it to work using Project Server REST API in SharePoint Hosted App. Can you send me the code that worked for you ? var projectContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current(); var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(projectContext, hostweburl); var restQueryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('" + projectUid + "')/Name"; var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl); executor.executeAsync({ url: encodeURI(restQueryUrl), method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) { alert("success:" + JSON.parse(data.bo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see from samples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj873844.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), they are using current web and not host web. From my understanding for Project it doesn't matter.
So you can try to call directly

```
https://yourorg-d2fcea9f69347f.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/SharePointAddIn/_api/ProjectServer/Projects
```

Or use `ps.js` and `PS.ProjectContext.get_current()`

Comment: It works thanks! No need to use "SP.AppContextSite".